# Accessing column values with columns set up as values of an index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, lambda

I have the following dataframe named ***df***:

```
     V1  V2
IDS
a    1    2    
b    3    4
```

If I print out the index and the columns, this is the result:

```
> print(df.index)
Index(['a','b'],dtype='object',name='IDS',length=2)
> print(df.columns)
Index(['V1','V2'],dtype='object',length=2)
```

I want to perform a calculation on these two columns (row-wise) and add this to a new column. I have tried the following, but I can't seem to access the column as expected.

```
df['sum'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['V1'] + row['V2'], axis=1)
```

I get the following error running the last line of code:

```
KeyError: ('V1', 'occurred at index a')
```

How do I access these columns?

---

Update: contrived example is not showing the error, here is the actual dataframe I am working with:

```
       DATE        ...   gathering_size_100_to_26     shelter_in_place
FIPS
10001  2020-01-22  ...   2020-01-01                   2020-01-01
10002  2020-01-22  ...   2020-01-01                   2020-01-02
10003  2020-02-25  ...   2020-01-01                   2020-01-03
...    ...         ...   ...                          ...
9013   2020-02-22  ...   2020-01-01                   2020-01-01
```

I want to take the difference between 'gathering_size_100_to_26' and 'DATE', as well as 'shelter_in_place' and 'DATE' and replace this value in place.

Comment: I'm not fully sure i understood the first part of your post,however, to calculate the 'sum' I don't think you need the apply, just use `df['sum'] = df['V1'] + df['V2']`

Comment: Your code works fine , for me. Also as prev comment says , you dont need apply

Answer (score 3):

```
df["v1_v2_sum"] = df["V1"] + df["V2"]
```

Anyways, avoid using df.apply and UDF, they have bad performance, and only needed when you have no options.

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0.8062, 0.9308], [0.364 , 0.6909]],index=['a','b'], columns=['V1','V2'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    V1       V2
a   0.8062  0.9308
b   0.3640  0.6909
```

```
df['sum'] = df.apply(sum,axis=1)


print(df)
```

Output:

````
      V1    V2       sum
a   0.8062  0.9308  1.7370
b   0.3640  0.6909  1.0549```
````

Answer (score 0):

I realized I had a typo.... what was stated above (but reworked for me instance) works.